# Is routes case-sensitive in Web API OData Service using ODataController?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-routing

i followed [this](http://www.tuicool.com/articles/BJVNnu) to learn how ODataController works, everything is OK but when i changed the request uri 
from

```
"localhost:49292/odata/Employees" //result: 200
```

to

```
"localhost:49292/odata/employees" //result: 404
```

to say one word: "odata" or "Odata" and "Employee" are all ok, but lowercase "employee" return 404. any explanation about this. Moreover, the routes in asp.net mvc is not case-sensitive afaik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about including a Route attribute and direct it to lower case. for Upper case web api will take care about it

`[Route("odata/employees")]`

add this on the top of the controller

if odata is common for every action then you can include `[RoutePrefix]` attribute

Comment: thanks. Adding attribute annotation is a big idea, but im using ODataConventionModelBuilder to add multiple model to an endpoint with the same route prefix. just don't no if controller name is case-sensitive.

Comment: yes they are case sensitive check out this article [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624180/Routing-Basics-in-ASP-NET-Web-API)

Answer (score 1):

You can manually do it using the ODataModelBuilder instead of the ODataConventionModelBuilder

e.g

```
        var builder = new ODataModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Order>("Employees");
        builder.EntitySet<Order>("employees");
```

this will work but your metadata will show 2 entity sets:

```
{
@odata.context: "http://localhost:62881/$metadata",
value: [
{
name: "Employees",
kind: "EntitySet",
url: "Employees"
},
{
name: "employees",
kind: "EntitySet",
url: "employees"
}
]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> lowercase "**employee**" return 404.

I hope you probably didn't have the typo like that.

AFAIK, there is a case limitation on filter and properties. (You can vote there https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/366 ) but not sure about the controller name..

You can create the REST server using web api without having oData as well..

Comment: thanks. it seems the controller name is case sensitive.